# Vertical align images in td

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have a `tr` having 4 `td`. These `td`s are `float:left`. Each td has an image of different size. Now i'm trying to `vertical-align` the images in center, so they look in a sequence.

But when i'm adding `vertical-align: middle` to them, it's not working. I even added `min-height` to `td`

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr8z4cyb/) and code:

```
    <table class="footer deviceWidth" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 13px; color: #fff; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 24px; vertical-align: top; padding:15px 0;">
                <h5 style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: normal;margin: 0;padding: 0;">The Company you'll Keep</h5>
                <table align="left" width="100%" class="companies" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr style="margin-bottom: 20px;display: inline-block;margin: 10px 0 0;">
                        <td style="min-height: 50px; float: left;width: 17%;margin-right: 2.5%;"><img src="http://placehold.it/490x310" width="346" height="50" alt="AA" style="height: auto;width: 100%;"></td>
                        <td style="min-height: 50px; float: left;width: 17%;margin-right: 2.5%;"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x50" width="456" height="50" alt="images" style="height: auto;width: 100%;"></td>
                        <td style="min-height: 50px; float: left;width: 17%;margin-right: 2.5%;"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x100" width="391" height="50" alt="images" style="height: auto;width: 100%;"></td>
                        <td style="min-height: 50px; float: left;width: 17%;margin-right: 2.5%;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="276" height="40" alt="images" style="height: auto;width: 100%;"></td>
                    </tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I'm using inline css because it's an email template.

Edit: Here's what i'm looking for: [image]

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you trying to vertically align the images so that their centers coincide (which is what your code does), or so that their tops coincide? Also if you are using floats you should probably get rid of the table structure altogether and just use img.

Comment: i want all images to appear in center( in corresponding to the image with the largest height). So, in the jsfiddle example, i want all images to appear in center corresponding to the 4th image.

Comment: Added an image of what i'm looking for

Comment: _“But when i'm adding `vertical-align: middle` to them, it's not working”_ – well of course it isn’t, _because_ you are floating the `td` – and thereby making them not behave like table-cell elements any more. What are you floating them for anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that does what you want without using tables. I've corrected the placeholder image widths as well. The width of the inline-block should be the sum of the widths of the images plus a bit extra to account for default margins, borders and padding (unless you explicitly zero them out).

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:1800px;">
<img src="http://placehold.it/490x310" width="490" height="310" alt="AA" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x50" width="200" height="50" alt="images" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/900x100" width="900" height="100" alt="images" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100" alt="images" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
</div>
```

If you really want to use tables, remove the `float:left` from each of the `td`'s and add `vertical-align:middle;`.

Comment: Actually it is just a small chunk of email template's footer. As Tables are best suited for email templates, that's why i have used tables. Can you do it in table, as per the current structure?

Comment: I've just added how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one thing to pull this off `vertical-align:middle;` to the element you want to have aligned in the middle. Wish they were all this easy huh?

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/wamepG